# PM2 home directory on Windows

Tags: node.js, pm2

I have a `logs` folder in C:\Users\username.pm2\logs, but whenever I try to start pm2 I am getting this error in my Logs:

```
PM2: 2015-11-20 13:23:32: Starting execution sequence in -fork mode- for app name:app id:0
PM2: 2015-11-20 13:23:32: Trace: [Error: can not create directories (logs/pids):ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir 'D:\Users\username\.pm2\logs']
```

So I think this is a config issue. How can I change the PM2 home directory to `C:\Users\username\.pm2` instead of `D:\Users\username\.pm2`?

Answer (score 1):

Apperantly this is an open issue on their github page, so I came up with two possible solutions:

you can make those folders on your other drive: `D:\Users\username\.pm2`

or just reisntall pm2:

```
npm uninstall -g pm2
npm install -g pm2
```